# Flash drive .docx disappeared files

Tags: microsoft-word, usb-flash-drive

I'm in trouble here

I have been writing important word documents and saving them on my flash drive

Some one deleated them all in another pc, I need help getting them back

I tried recovering word temporary files, couldn't find them
Please

Comment: I don't understand this.

Comment: are you sure they were deleted, there are many common virus's which target USB drives that hide files. An easy way to check is to open a cmd prompt and navigate to your drive then type in dir /ah this will show all hidden files

Comment: Have you tried any data recovery tools like TestDisk or Recuva ? Is this on a Windows or Mac ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you sure they were deleted, there are many common virus's which target USB drives that hide files. An easy way to check is to open a cmd prompt and navigate to your drive then type in `dir /ah` this will show all hidden files.

If the files are there but hidden, type the following into your command prompt where F: is the letter of your drive:

```
attrib * f: /s /d -s -h -r
```

this will unhide all files and folders

If there are no files showing, your other option is to use third party recovery software, there are many free ones available, just Google "recovery utility free"

Comment: Or instead of Googling, perhaps start by searching the _many_ questions and answers regarding recovering files here on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way yo know if your files are deleted or are still there in your memory is to open the "This computer" folder (Win key + E) and look if the bar which measures the amount of free space available is partially, half or fully filled. If the bar is partially filled then your files are there, but only hidden. You can follow the steps described above by @Kilisi to unhide your files.

P.S. The correct format for the attrib command is:

```
attrib /s /d -s -h -r *.*
```

And it's normal that you receive a Denied access error for the System Volume Information folder, because the folder has permissions that doesn't allow certain actions to certain users.

[image: Security properties tab]

Comment: your attrib will work if you navigate to the drive letter and run it from there, mine is also valid syntax but you don't need to cd into the drive letter first. For your syntax best practice would be attrib /s /d -s -h -r e: *.* I think, for some reason the asterixs aren't showing but should be one on each side of the final dot

Comment: I tried it the way you wrote it, but when doing that I receive an error which says I used an "incorrect parameters format" (I have a partition with that letter and also tried it with an external USB memory changing the letter). That's why I suggested the command I always use and always works for me.

Comment: in that case I'm probably wrong, sorry, I typed it off the top of my head, it looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, if I try it from a command prompt it's incorrect. It will only work if I type it directly into the 'run' dialog box, Otherwise I have to cd to the drive and leave out the drive letter and then it will work in a prompt.