# Flash drive .docx disappeared

Tags: microsoft-word, usb-flash-drive

it starts here [Flash drive .docx disappeared files](https://superuser.com/questions/989952/flash-drive-docx-disappeared-files#)

I have tried Jesús Hagiwara and Kilisi answers, and nothing work

```
    Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

    C:\Users\Dell>D:

    D:\>dir\ah
     Le volume dans le lecteur D s'appelle Princesse
     Le numéro de série du volume est 40D9-4FE9

     Répertoire de D:\

    Fichier introuvable

    D:\>attrib /s /d -s -h -r *.*
    Impossible de modifier l'attribut - D:\.Trash-1000\files\Autorun.inf\lpt1.UsbFix

    La cible du lien symbolique D:\.Trash-1000\files\Screenshot from 2015-10-01 18:2
    1:32.png n'existe pas
D:\>
```

What is this reputation thing I can't even make a comment

Comment: "What is this reputation thing I can't even make a comment" Welcome! You should spend a few seconds and [take the Tour](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: I read your other post, but not all the comments and answers though. It sounds like you need to find a `data recovery tool` and start there.  If the files aren't hidden on your drive and the file `attrib` commands don't make a difference, then find a recovery tool that'll work for your need and do some testing and research and start there.  Just do some google searches and see what you can find to attempt to recover deleted items from a USB thumb drive. I encourage you to read the 'take a tour' as well to clarify the "reputation thing". Respectfully~

Comment: (1) It's good to post the exact output that you're getting on your screen, but, if it's in a non-English language, it's very helpful if you provide a best-effort translation into English.  (2) Try `dir /ah` instead of `dir\ah`.

Comment: Your other account is unregistered. Use the contact us link to request an account merger and you'll have control of the other question.